# Disable Codeigniter logging and allow native PHP logging

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging, error-handling

I am running Codeigniter 2.1.4 and as far as I can tell CodeIgniter is intercepting PHP error messages and storing them in `/application/logs`

I would like to disable CodeIgniter logging and simply allow the native PHP error log to get used.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the top of the main codeigniter index.php file 
theres different ways of defining the environment but you can just define it on that index page. what you want is 'production'

```
    // comment this line out
    //define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');

   // put in this line
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
```

you will see in the code that codeigniter also accommodates your php version. 
OR you can just go under that section of code and paste this in

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

a faster sloppier way of switching between showing errors or not.

==== **edit**

this post was in reply to this comment you made:

> This is great information but unfortunately CI seems to still be
>   intercepting "Notice" level messages and is outputting them to the
>   browser.

so the above instructions controls if error messages are sent to the browser. otherwise in terms of codeigniter 'logging' your errors - you can turn off codeigniter logging in application/config and do whatever type of logging you want.

Comment: So this is supposed to make CodeIgniter stop intercepting log entries which I want to go to PHP's native log file?

Answer (score 0):

on /application/config.php
check if $config['log_threshold'] = 0;

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Error Logging Threshold
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you have enabled error logging, you can set an error threshold to
| determine what gets logged. Threshold options are:
| You can enable error logging by setting a threshold over zero. The
| threshold determines what gets logged. Threshold options are:
|
|   0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
|   1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
|   2 = Debug Messages
|   3 = Informational Messages
|   4 = All Messages
|
| For a live site you'll usually only enable Errors (1) to be logged otherwise
| your log files will fill up very fast.
|
*/
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;
```

Comment: This is great information but unfortunately CI seems to still be intercepting "Notice" level messages and is outputting them to the browser. These are not getting logged in the CI log nor the PHP log. I've found that if I comment out Line #72 - `set_error_handler('_exception_handler');` of `/core/CodeIgniter.php` then I get the desired results. I would hate to mess with the core though :/